# Getline to read from text file

Tags: c++

So, I am trying to read name, number and adress of a contact from a text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include "PhoneBook.h"

void readFromFile(string filename)
{
    int n = 0, i;
    string temp_name, temp_number, temp_adress, nstr;
    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());

    getline(fin, nstr);
    n = atoi(nstr.c_str());

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        getline(fin, temp_name);
        getline(fin, temp_number);
        getline(fin, temp_adress);

        contactbook->addPerson(temp_name, temp_number, temp_adress);
    }
}
```

main passes the file name. But I am not sure why this error appears:

Error   C2780   'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)': expects 3 arguments - 2 provided

Comment: 1: You don't need it, the file will be closed when it goes out of scope anyway. 2: `std::getline(...)`? And you have included the needed headers? It would be easier to help you properly if you shown us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and a full and complete and undedited copy-paste of the error output.

Comment: What is the format of the file you are reading from?

Comment: its often easier to read via `std::cin`. Sometimes you need `getline` but if each line contains only a single entry you dont

Comment: Headers are:  <iostream>, <string>, <fstream>, <stdlib.h>, "stdafx.h", "Person.h", "PhoneBook.h"
I am reading from .txt

Comment: Also Error: Error C2780 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)': expects 3 arguments - 2 provided

Comment: Are you actually building with pre-compiled headers? VC might be ignoring everything before the stdafx.h - the idea is that you include your C++ headers (and large not-often-changed project headers) from stdafx.h instead and include that as the first include in every source. But I doubt that's causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are using Visual studio that has its own compiler. 
As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/3ah895zy(v=vs.110)) explain the function string::getline has this declaration

```
    template<class _E, class _TYPE, class _A> inline 
   basic_istream<_E, _TYPE>& getline( 
   basic_istream<_E, _TYPE>& Istream, 
   basic_string<_E, _TYPE, _A>& Xstring, 
   const _E _D=_TYPE::newline( ) 
   );
```

so you are missing a parameter that in your case is '\n'. 
Try this code

```
void readFromFile(string filename)
{
    int n = 0, i;
    string temp_name, temp_number, temp_adress, nstr;
    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());

    getline(fin, nstr,'\n');
    n = atoi(nstr.c_str());

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        getline(fin, temp_name,'\n');
        getline(fin, temp_number,'\n');
        getline(fin, temp_adress,'\n');

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using VS 2015. I missed to say that, Sorry.

New error: 
Error C2784 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'int'

Comment: Every getline causes multiple errors, some of them old C2780, some  are C2784

Comment: try to add std:: at the beginning of getline

Comment: @Dragonith can you tell me what couse the error? I'm interested

Comment: Missing () on a function referencing temp_number and temp_adress, beginner mistake. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Don't worry it was a pleasure